# new Audio(url) with class

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-audio

After I make a new audio element in javascript, I want the element to also have a class assigned.

```
const audio = new Audio(url)
```

Can I declare an audio element that also has a class. And how so?

Comment: `audio.className = 'yourclass'` ? since `audio` is an `instanceof` `HTMLElement`

Comment: Thank you! so frustrating to get stumped by something so simple. I kept looking for ways to set it as I created the instance but this is perfect.